# Inserting a variable in a raw sql query Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am inside a function in a controller.

So from the Form, I get a value for a variable, say:

```
$x = "whatever";
```

Then I need to embed that variable (so, its value), in the WHERE statement. If I hardcode the value, it brings a correct result, but I have tried in all ways to insert that variable without success. Well, supposing that I manage to use that variable, then I will have to look into binding to avoid sql injection, but so far, I would say, see if that variable can get used in the query.

I have tried, double quotes, concatenation . $vx . , curly braces {$x}, the variable plain like this $variable, but either gives syntax errors in some cases, (concatenation), or if I just embed the variable like this where author = $x, it tells me that it can't find the column named $x

```
$x = "whatever";
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT 
                           t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
                       FROM (
                           SELECT
                               p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
                           FROM posts p

                           INNER JOIN styles s
                               ON s.post_id = p.id
                           WHERE author = $x    
                           GROUP BY p.id
                       ) t
                       INNER JOIN rates r
                           ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle'
                           ));
```

Comment: So let's start with the simple:  php doesn't do variable interpolation unless you use double quotes.  Let's start with that.  Change your sql statement to use "SELECT ..." and please report whatever behavior is occurring.

Comment: The 2nd obvious thing I see --- is author a char/varchar value?  If so your sql syntax has to be WHERE author = '$x' .  The purpose of the RAW method is to inject raw sql, so it's not going to do any magic for you.  You have to construct a string that you could copy into a command line tool and have it run.

Comment: You solved it! Please, put it as an answer to get  your credit. You dont have those over 6000 points intellect for nothing.

Comment: Ok, no worries, glad to have helped.

Comment: I am more grateful but if we dont put it as an answer, everybody is going to keep coming to check it as it will remain like unsolved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This appears to be a simple PHP variable interpolation issue.

`DB::raw()` wants literally *raw* SQL. So there are a couple of issues that need to be fixed in the SQL string you are passing.

1. PHP Variable interpolation (injecting variables into a string) only happens if you use double quotes around the string.  With single quotes it becomes a string constant.
2. If Author is a `char`/`varchar`, then SQL syntax requires quotes around the string in your raw SQL statement.  Query builders typically take care of these issues for you, but you are going around them.

So the "fixed" version of this would be:

```
$x = "whatever";
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 
                       t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
                   FROM (
                       SELECT
                           p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
                       FROM posts p

                       INNER JOIN styles s
                           ON s.post_id = p.id
                       WHERE author = '$x'    
                       GROUP BY p.id
                   ) t
                   INNER JOIN rates r
                       ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle"
                   ));
```

Like all interpolation, this opens you up to the possibility of SQL injection if the variable being interpolated comes from user input.  From the original question it is unclear whether this is a problem.

`DB::select()` has an option that allows you to pass an array of parameters that is inherently safe from SQL injection. In that case the solution would be:

```
$x = "whatever";
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT 
                       t.id, t.AvgStyle, r.RateDesc
                   FROM (
                       SELECT
                           p.id, ROUND(AVG(s.Value)) AS AvgStyle
                       FROM posts p

                       INNER JOIN styles s
                           ON s.post_id = p.id
                       WHERE author = :author
                       GROUP BY p.id
                   ) t
                   INNER JOIN rates r
                       ON r.digit = t.AvgStyle"
                   ),
                       array('author' => $x)
                   );
```

Comment: Side note: there is no parameter binding going on here, nor escaping, so readers using this code should ensure that `$x` does not come from user input.

Comment: @halfer From my testing, the parameter is made safe as I was able to use `where name = :name` with `['name' => "o'brien"]`. If it didn't escape that apostrophe, the query would have failed.

Comment: @halfer:  Your comment is pertinent to the non-parameter passing version, which I personally don't advocate nor would I use.  Parameterized queries is the way to go if for no other reason than you don't need escaping, which also innoculates you from SQL injection.

Comment: This method doesn't work if you have more than one value within select method

Comment: I don't know what you mean -- "more than one value in select method".

Answer (score 7):

Regarding [this tutorial](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries)

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = :somevariable"), array(
   'somevariable' => $someVariable,
 ));
```

Comment: This method doesn't work if you have more than one value within select method

Answer (score -1):

This is one example for you to insert variable in a raw sql laravel

```
        $query_result = Event::select(
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN status = "draft" THEN "draft" 
            WHEN events.end_time <= \''.$now.'\' THEN "closed"
            ELSE "available"
            END) AS status'))
            ->orderBy('status')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Please explain your solution instead of showing only code.