# Use a php function with eloquent queries in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a model `Location`, and it has a one to one relationship with another model `Address` with attributes like `latitude` and `longitude`, and I'm working on an endpoint to get a list of locations based their distance to user. So my `GET` request, for example, looks something like `/locations?latitude=70.00&longitude=-80.01`.

In my `LocationController` I already have a function like `haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo)` that takes 4 arguments as float and return the distance to user input location as a float.

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, isMile = false) { 
    if ($isMile) {
        $earthRadius = self::EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILE;
    else {
        $earthRadius = self::EARTH_RADIUS_IN_KM;
    }

    $dLat = deg2rad($latitudeTo - $latitudeFrom);  
    $dLon = deg2rad($longitudeTo - $longitudeFrom);  

    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);  
    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));  
    $d = $earthRadius * $c;  

    return $d;
}
```

My question is, how do I use this function as part of my eloquent query to get the distance? My eloquent query currently looks something like this:

```
$distance = self::haversineGreatCircleDistance($latitude, $longitude, 'latitude', 'longitude') . ' AS distance';

$query = Location::select('*', \DB::raw($distance))
->with('address')
->sortBy('distance');
```

However it's not working and all the distances calculated are the same as if the second `latitude` and `longitude` parameters were 0. And if there's no way to make the query work with php functions, what is a better solution? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks so much!

Comment: i think your haversineGreatCircleDistance must be in your model. Can you shoe your haversineGreatCircleDistance function?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618764/inserting-a-variable-in-a-raw-sql-query-laravel#37619436 I think it will might help you.

Comment: you send only the distance to your Location model. I think you must send latitude and longtidue to the model too.

Comment: i think it must similar to this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-find-nearest-cities-from-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: you are put  the number in `DB::raw()`, and is the method `haversineGreatCircleDistance` in your Location Model?