# Trying to include Variables inside a Laravel Raw Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, list, raw

Got myself tangled up trying to put a statement into a ::raw query:

```
  $rawStatement = "DISTINCT Product";
  $product_codes = DB::table('Chemical')
          ->JOIN('ChemicalTarget', 'Chemical.ChemicalID', '=' , 'ChemicalTarget.ChemicalID')
          ->select(DB::raw(function($query) with ($rawStatement) {
                   $query->select(DB::raw($rawStatement));
                   })
          ->orderBy('Product', 'asc')
          ->groupBy('Product')
          ->lists('Product'); //<-- This is required for existing front end.
```

Eventually I'm going to try to put this into that statement:

```
 CONCAT(Product, ' ', CASE WHEN :stateReg != 'Y' THEN '(not :state reg)' ELSE '' END) as label
```

with

```
 array('stateReg' => $stateRegistered, 'state' => $state)
```

and

```
 ->orderBy('label', 'asc')
          ->groupBy('label')
          ->lists('label');
```

If I replace

```
 ->select(DB::raw(function($query) with ($rawStatement) {
                   $query->select(DB::raw($rawStatement));
                   })
```

with

```
 ->select(DB::raw("DISTINCT Product")
```

Of course it works..

I was using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618764/inserting-a-variable-in-a-raw-sql-query-laravel/37619436) as reference to build my initial process, hit a snag when I added a 2nd variable, but even when I reduced it to one, I could not get ->lists() to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

> The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

Now that being said you would replace `lists` to [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-results) function(search for `Retrieving A List Of Column Values` in this page)

***How to pass multiple variables in closure function***: You can use `use` keyword and a list of options like below.

```
->select(DB::raw(function($query) use ($a, $b, $c) {
    // use $a, $b, $c
 })
```

But in this case you can omit this closure by just directly putting raw text inside `DB::raw()`. So your query can be like this using `$stateRegistered` and `$state` variables.

```
$products = DB::table('Chemical')
          ->join('ChemicalTarget', 'Chemical.ChemicalID', '=', 'ChemicalTarget.ChemicalID')
          ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(Product, ' ', CASE WHEN '$stateRegistered' != 'Y' THEN '(not $state)' ELSE '' END) as label"))
          ->orderBy('label', 'asc')
          ->groupBy('label')
          ->pluck('label');
```

Comment: I have run several tests, attempting pluck on the original code, which fails. (htmlstrings can't accept objects / arrays) but the rest of it worked. Thanks