# How to call a PHP/Laravel function for a value of a table column dynamically in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need the query result where multiple tables are joined. But, for one of those tables, I need to call a function which uses a column value, does some operations and returns the final value. I need to export the query result in a CSV.

Below is a simplified example. How can I use `getURL` function in a query? Is there any other way to achieve this? (I am using Laravel 7.)

#### Tables

##### `Activities`

| id | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | running | ABC |
| 2 | dancing | XYZ |

##### `Activity_multimedia`

| id | activity_id | type | multimedia_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Vid | abc1.mp4 |
| 2 | 1 | Img | abc2.jpeg |
| 3 | 2 | Img | abc3.jpeg |
| 4 | 2 | Img | abc4.jpeg |
| 5 | 2 | Vid | abc5.mp4 |

##### My code

```php
public function query() {
    return Activity::query()
        ->selectRaw(
            'activities.id',
            'activities.title',
            'multimedia.multimedia_locations'
        )
        ->leftJoin(
            DB::raw('(SELECT activity_multimedia.activity_id, GROUP_CONCAT(activity_multimedia.type SEPARATOR \', \') as type, GROUP_CONCAT('. DB::raw($this->GetURL('activity_multimedia.type', 'activity_multimedia.multimedia_location')).' SEPARATOR \', \') as multimedia_locations, FROM activity_multimedia GROUP BY activity_multimedia.activity_id) as multimedia'), 'multimedia.activity_id', "=", "activities.id"
        )
        ->groupBy('activities.id', 'multimedia.multimedia_locations')
        ->distinct();
}

public function GetURL($fileType = null, $fileName = null) {
    $URL = 'https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/';
    $type = '';
    if ($fileType === 'Img') {
        $type = 'Image';
    } elseif ($fileType === 'Vid') {
        $type = 'Video';
    }
    
    return $URL.'/'.$type.$fileName;
}
```

#### Result

| id | title | multimedia_locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | running | https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/Video/abc1.mp4,https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/Image/abc2.jpeg |
| 2 | dancing | https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/Image/abc3.jpeg,https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/Image/abc4.jpeg,https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/Video/abc5.mp4 |

Comment: Not familiar with laravel, but you run your query and process the results. In that order.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618764/inserting-a-variable-in-a-raw-sql-query-laravel    basically, declare the variable and use double-quote to single quote syntax

Comment: @Cameron yes, but, the problem here is I need to pass type and location column values to getURL function.